# simple jquery if statement with dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I would like for the div '.container' to be clickable ONLY if there is content in the div '#ajax". I have coded the following basic jquery script.

```
if ('#ajax:empty') {
    $('.container').css('pointer-events', 'none');
}
```

It works great when the page loads, '.container' is not clickable. However, when the user loads in AJAX content '.container' is still not clickable.

Comment: That code is executed only once (it's not an event handler).  You should handle the AJAX complete event and then set the container to clickable.

Comment: you load your data lively but you want to check that when your page load!?

Comment: can you please tell me if the 'if' statement is inside an event function such as click or in document ready?

Answer (score 0):

the success of your call you will have to do the reverse style withdrawing

```
$.ajax({
   url: "url",
   sucess: function(){  $('.container').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$('.container').click(function(e){
      if($("#ajax").html().length == 0){
            //Disable pointer events
            e.preventDefault();
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying it but doesn't seem to work. I even tried $('.container').css('pointer-events', 'none');

Comment: what gets trigger when you click the .container div?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" ); // write what you need after user loads the ajax content
});
```